# Thread is not getting scheduled after some time or doesn't comes up

Tags: c, linux

I am creating a thread in an application(which has other threads as well), through following code:

```
schedulerParam.sched_priority = PRI_MIDDLE;
    pthread_attr_init(&pThreadAttrAlarms);
    pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&pThreadAttrAlarms, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&pThreadAttrAlarms, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&pThreadAttrAlarms, SCHED_RR);
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pThreadAttrAlarms, &schedulerParam);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&pThreadAttrAlarms, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);

    printf("Going to create alarms thread.\n");
    err = pthread_create (&alarmsThread, &pThreadAttrAlarms, /*(void *)*/ alarmsThreadFunc, NULL);
    if(err < 0)
    {
        perror("Error: alarms thread create error\n");
        printf("Error: alarms thread create error, err:%d \n", err);
        return 0;
    }
    pthread_setname_np(alarmsThread, "alarmsThrd");
    //Run alarms thread on core 0
    setThreadAffinity(alarmsThread);
    pthread_join(alarmsThread, NULL);
```

But this alarmsThread stops getting scheduled after some seconds, only for few seconds or minute it gets scheduled. This thread creates a TCP client to connect with a remote TCP server. And this thread keeps on going to sleep for 10 sec, and then on waking up checks for alarms and if alarms get raised then they are send to TCP server.
While alarmsThread doesn't gets scheduled but `ps -T` output(for alarmsThread) is following:

```
 1915 root      749m S    {alarmsThrd} //bin/controlplaneapp 0 0
```

It is strange behavior that why this thread doesn't gets scheduled after a while. Moreover, if I put in a sleep of 60 sec or so at start of function alarmsThreadFunc in order to start this thread later, then sometimes the thread doesn't comes up at all. Please note that all these findings that it doen't gets scheduled or doesn't even comes up have been ascertained through console prints.

Please help as I've got stuck in this since quite some time. Thanks in advance.

I tried running a alarmsThread but it isn't running after a while or not running at all.

Below is the infinite loop snippet from alarmsThreadFunc:

```
   while (1)
    {
        if(1 == EMS_CONN_STATE)
           retVal = sendPendingAlarms(sockfd);
        checkForAlarms(sockfd);
        if (0 == EMS_CONN_STATE)
        {
           retVal = connectToEms(&sockfd, nmsPort, nmsHostIp);
        }
        sleep(10);
     }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using std::thread (from C++11) or std::jthread (C++20) ? With std::thread you should also use std::mutex and std::scoped_lock which will help avoid problems with "forgetting" unlocks. Can you also show your alarms thread implementatino because I have a feeling the problem is in that code not the code you show

Comment: When the thread "doesn't come up", what does the debugger have to say about your thread and it's stack trace?

Comment: Essentially this is a C code. And I am using the mutex with lock-unlock pairs, that doesn't seems to have any problem though. I'll see to paste alarmsThread code here.

Comment: I don't have a debugger, its a Linux like platform on which I am running it, but I can't attach gdb or any other debugger on this platform.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Only tag the one you are actually using. Based on your earlier comment, I removed [tag:c++]